# Creating Gaussian random variable with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution, probability-density

By using `randn` function I want to create a Gaussian random variable `X` such that `X ~ N(2,4)` and plot this simulated PDF together with theoretic curve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw Normal Distribution Graph of a Sample in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831690/draw-normal-distribution-graph-of-a-sample-in-matlab)

Comment: Also see [this answer's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902148/8239061) which has an example to both generate samples to estimate the PDF and compare with the theoretical PDF.  You can also repeat [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876868/8239061) but leave off the *truncation*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random Numbers with Gaussian and Uniform Distributions in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13844944/8239061)

Answer (score 7):

Matlab `randn` generates realisations from a normal distribution with zero mean and a standard deviation of 1. 
Samples from any other normal distribution can simply be generated via:

```
numSamples = 1000;
mu = 2;
sigma = 4;
samples = mu + sigma.*randn(numSamples, 1);
```

You can verify this by plotting the histogram:

```
figure;hist(samples(:));
```

See the [matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
N = 1000;
x = [-20:20];
samples = 2 + 4*randn(N, 1);
ySamples = histc(samples,x) / N;
yTheoretical = pdf('norm', x, 2, 4);
plot(x, yTheoretical, x, ySamples)
```

`randn(N, 1)` creates an `N`-by-1 vector.

`histc` is histogram count by bins given in `x` - you can use `hist` to plot the result immediately, but here we want to divide it by `N`.

`pdf` contains many useful PDFs, normal is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

remember this: X ~ N(mean, variance)

randn in matlab produces normal distributed random variables W with zero mean and unit variance.
To change the mean and variance to be the random variable X (with custom mean and variance), follow this equation:
X = mean + standard_deviation*W
Please be aware of that standard_deviation is square root of variance.

```
N = 1000;
x = [-20:20];
samples = 2 + sqrt(4)*randn(N, 1);
ySamples = histc(samples,x) / N;
yTheoretical = pdf('norm', x, 2, sqrt(4)); %put std_deviation not variance
plot(x, yTheoretical, x, ySamples)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way to achieve this using one line of code is to use :

```
mu = 2;
sigma = 2;
samples = normrnd(mu,sigma,M,N);
```

This will generate an **MxN** matrix, sampled from `N(μ,)`, (`= N(2,2)` in this particular case).
For additional information, see [`normrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html).

Comment: How is this different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101180/8239061) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20570900/8239061)?  Plus OP wanted N(2,4), not N(2,2). Also, question explicitly wants to look at the empirical [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and compare to theoretical one.