# Random Numbers with Gaussian and Uniform Distributions in matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I want generate a number in Gaussian and Uniform distributions in matlab.
I know this function  `randi` and `rand()` but all of them are in normal (Gaussian) distribution. How can a generate a random number in uniform distribution?

Comment: A normal distribution *is* a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @zhilevan: Did I manage to read your mind in the updated answer ?

Comment: @mmgp, tnx for your attention, yes I read it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `rand(dimensions)` for a *Uniform Distribution* between 0 and 1.

Use `randn(dimensions) * sqrt(sigma) + mu` for a *Gaussian Distribution* with a mean of *mu* and standard deviation of *sigma*.

[image: Uniform Distribution]

[image: Normal Distribution]

Comment: `randnrm` **is not valid function** in matlab 2011 :(

Comment: Standard deviation and variance are different things, the answer is currently wrong. There is another answer here that is correct.

Comment: may i ask a question. I want the random number in range (0,1), so that I try randn() * sqrt(1) + 0. I got number lager than 1, and some negative number -2, -3. What is wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong- randn() gives a normal distribution, which is not bounded between 0 and 1. See wikipedia for more info and example plots.

Answer (score 7):

`randn` is the function to generate Gaussian distributed variables (`randi` and `rand` produce uniformly distributed ones).

Comment: no, if you try help `randn` in matlab 2011 see this         help randn RANDN Normally distributed pseudorandom numbers.
    R = RANDN(N) returns an N-by-N matrix containing pseudorandom values drawn
    from the standard normal distribution.  RANDN(M,N) or RANDN([M,N]) returns
    an M-by-N matrix. RANDN(M,N,P,...) or RANDN([M,N,P,...]) returns an
    M-by-N-by-P-by-... array. RANDN returns a scalar.  RANDN(SIZE(A)) returns
    an array the same size as A.
 
    Note: The size inputs M, N, P, ... should be nonnegative integers.
    Negative integers are treated as 0.

Comment: Yes.  Normally means "Gaussian".  You want rand and randn, as others have said.

Comment: @zhilevan: normal distribution is also called Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 6):

You can generate any distribution from rand().

For example , lets say you want to generate 100000 samples for rayleigh dist.The way to do this is that you invert the cdf of that particular function.The basic idea is that since the cdf has to be between 0 and 1 , we can find the value of the random variable by inputting the value of cdf b/w 0 and 1. So for rayleigh, it would be

```
for i = 1:100000
  data(i) = (2*sigma^2 *(-(log(1 - rand(1,1)))))^.5;
end
```

You can do something similar for gaussian distribution.

Comment: In one line: `sigma = 3; tmp =  (2*sigma^2 *(-(log(1 - rand(1e6, 1))))).^.5; hist(tmp, 100)` .

Answer (score 5):

Congrulations, you already generating pseudo-random numbers with a gaussian distribution. Normal distribution is a synonym for it.

The only other possible interpretation I can get from your question is that you want something that has mean != 0 and/or variance != 1. To do that, simply perform `mean + sqrt(var) * randn(X)`.

Comment: pease  generate for me on number with **uniform** and another with **gaussin** distributes. tnx

Comment: You need to look up your books, or other sources. Did you read the first phrase of my answer ? They are synonyms, i.e., they are the same thing.

Comment: yes I read it, I want 2 distributes, 1:gaussian(normal ) ,2:uniform

Comment: Ok, an `uniform` one is obtained by the the functions you already posted. Then you asked for a `normal` and `gaussian`, which are the same thing. So you already know how to generate an `uniform`, and `normal`/`gaussian`, what else is left ?

Answer (score 4):

It is true you can generate just about anything from `rand` but that it isn't always convenient, especially for some complicated distributions.

MATLAB has introduced [Probability Distribution Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html#bum5reu) which make this a lot easier and allow you to seamlessly access `mean`, `var`, `truncate`, `pdf`, `cdf`, `icdf` (inverse transform), `median`, and other functions.

You can fit a distribution to data.  In this case, we use `makedist` to **define** the *probability distribution object*. Then we can **generate** using `random`.

```
% Parameters
mu = 10; 
sigma = 3;
a = 5; b = 15;
N = 5000;

% Older Approaches Still Work
rng(1775)
Z = randn(N,1);    % Standard Normal  Z~N(0,1)
X = mu + Z*sigma;  % X ~ Normal(mu,sigma)

U = rand(N,1);     % U ~ Uniform(0,1)
V = a + (b-a)*U;   % V ~ Uniform(a,b)

% New Approaches Are Convenient
rng(1775)
pdX = makedist('Normal',mu,sigma);
X2 = random(pdX,N,1);

pdV = makedist('Uniform',a,b);
V2 = random(pdV,N,1);
```

A reproducible example:

[image: Histograms]

```
Support = (0:0.01:20)';
figure 
s(1) = subplot(2,2,1)
h(1) = histogram(X,'Normalization','pdf')
xlabel('Normal')
s(2) = subplot(2,2,2)
h(2) = histogram(V,'Normalization','pdf')
xlabel('Uniform')
s(3) = subplot(2,2,3), hold on, box on
h(3) = histogram(X2,'Normalization','pdf')
plot(Support,pdf(pdX,Support),'r-','LineWidth',1.2)
xlabel('Normal (new)')
s(4) = subplot(2,2,4), hold on, box on
h(4) = histogram(V2,'Normalization','pdf')
plot(Support,pdf(pdV,Support),'r-','LineWidth',1.2)
xlabel('Uniform (new)')
xlim(s,[0 20])
```

References:
[Uniform Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous))
[Normal (Gaussian) Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Answer (score 2):

Following raj's answer: by using the **Box-Muller Transform** you can generate independent standard Normal/Gaussian random numbers:

```
N = 1e6; z = sqrt(-2*log(rand(N, 1))) .* cos(2*pi * rand(N, 1)); figure; hist(z, 100)
N = 1e6; z = sqrt(-2*log(rand(N, 1))) .* sin(2*pi * rand(N, 1)); figure; hist(z, 100)
```

If you want to apply the **Inverse Transformation Method**, you can use the Inverse Complementary Error Function (erfcinv):

```
N = 1e6; z = -sqrt(2) * erfcinv(2 * rand(1e6, 1)); figure; hist(z, 100)
```

But I hope `randn` works better.