# Drawing pseudorandoms from a truncated normal distribution

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, truncated

Matlab has the function randn to draw from a normal distribution e.g.

```
x = 0.5 + 0.1*randn()
```

draws a pseudorandom number from a normal distribution of mean 0.5 and standard deviation 0.1.

Given this, is the following Matlab code equivalent to sampling from a normal distribution truncated at 0 at 1?

```
    while x <=0 || x > 1

    x = 0.5 + 0.1*randn();

    end
```

Comment: How your variables (cr,c crmean) are declared and computed?

Comment: cr is an array of values. cr(c) is the c'th element. crMean is a constant e.g. 0.5. c is a loop iterator.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/_WXo4FhVP4g) if you have the statistics toolbox. However, according to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.4010v1) your approach is reasonable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MATLAB's [Probability Distribution Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html) makes sampling from truncated distributions very easy.

You can use the [`makedist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html) and [`truncate()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.truncate.html) functions to define the object and then modify (truncate it) to prepare the object for the [`random()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html) function which allows generating random variates from it.

```
% MATLAB R2017a
pd = makedist('Normal',0.5,0.1)     % Normal(mu,sigma)
pdt = truncate(pd,0,1)              % truncated to interval (0,1)
sample = random(pdt,numRows,numCols)  % Sample from distribution `pdt`
```

Once the object is created (here it is `pdt`, the truncated version of `pd`), you can use it in a variety of function calls.

To **generate samples**, `random(pdt,m,n)` produces a *m* x *n* array of samples from `pdt`.

---

Further, if you want to avoid use of toolboxes, [this answer from @Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100556/8239061) is correct (proof below).

[image: Comparison of @Luis Mendo code results with theoretical results]

```
figure, hold on
h = histogram(cr,'Normalization','pdf','DisplayName','@Luis Mendo samples');
X = 0:.01:1;
p = plot(X,pdf(pdt,X),'b-','DisplayName','Theoretical (w/ truncation)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you vectorize? It will probably be faster:

```
N = 1e5; % desired number of samples
m = .5; % desired mean of underlying Gaussian
s = .1; % desired std of underlying Gaussian
lower = 0; % lower value for truncation
upper = 1; % upper value for truncation

remaining = 1:N;
while remaining
    result(remaining) = m + s*randn(1,numel(remaining)); % (pre)allocates the first time
    remaining = find(result<=lower | result>upper);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the following steps 
1. Draw a random value from uniform distribution, u.
2. Assuming the normal distribution is truncated at a and b. get

```
u_bar = F(a)*u +F(b) *(1-u)
```

3. Use the inverse of F

```
epsilon= F^{-1}(u_bar)
```

epsilon is a random value for the truncated normal distribution.

Comment: Where is the formula from? Help provide reference please!