# How to use the randn function in Matlab to create an array of values (range 0-10) of size 1,000 that follows a Gaussian distribution?

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

```
y = 1.*randn(1000,1) + 5
```

Now the mean is 5 and the variance is 1. But it's still possible to get a number out of range(0,10)

Comment: By definition of the distribution, any value is possible with a certain small probability. Are you looking for a truncated normal distribution? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Yes, I'm looking for a truncated normal distribution. I'm not sure if I can realize it with randn function,

Comment: Once you have the name, it is actually easy to find. The question was previously asked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18099201/2732801